# WordPress login button not working from frontend

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

http://www.thegameraccess.com/

Hi this is my website on wp when you click on login or register nothing happens. I tried to replace JQuery version to 1.13.1 and also tried CSS/JS but nothing is happening. On Google chrome console I get this error **Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined**

Comment: The login link has a href value of '#' and an onclick value of 'return false' so it's not going to do anything on it's own. Is there JavaScript somewhere that's supposed to be augmenting the functionality? Also, what's the desired behavior, e.g. redirect to a specific page, open a modal, etc.

Comment: Yes there will be modal open fulllscreen login

Comment: jQuery is not your problem. That warning appears from before you click on that elements, likely because somewhere something is using it before it gets loaded. But when the page finish to load jQuery is working. Just guessing, there should be a library that use the `.pafl-trigger-overlay pafl-register-link` class that dind't get loaded or iniciated.